# Synonymize [case-when] to [case]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

### Synonymize [case-when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-when) to [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case)

Tags mean the same according to their description and usage. Tag [case-when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-when) has more descriptive name, but [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) is much more frequent and has much better wiki. Other relevant synonyms: [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) and [case-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-expression).

#### Question number

- [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) – 4926 questions,
- [case-when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-when) – 428 questions,
- [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) – 308 questions,
- [case-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-expression) — 29 questions.

Comment: You can add [tag:case-statement] to the list, another synonym with 308 questions currently.